# Compute Exp(At)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A= \begin{bmatrix}
    1&3\\
    2&2
  \end{bmatrix}$, compute $\exp(At)$.

I need help help on computing a matrix exponential.
solution according to [wolfamalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrixexp(t%20%7B%7B1,3%7D,%7B2,2%7D%7D)):

The process that I settled on was.

1.get the eigenvalues 2. get the eigenvector 3. Diagonalization of A 4.get exponential matrix with $D = C^{-1}AC$

**Eigenvalues**

$\det{(\lambda I-A)} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda-1&-3\\
    -2&\lambda-2
  \end{bmatrix} \lambda_1 = 4$,$\lambda_2 = -1$

**Eigenvectors I reworked it and $v_2 = (-3,2)$**

$Av_1 = \lambda_1v_1 \Rightarrow (A-\lambda_1)v_1 = 0$

$\Rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda_1-1&-3\\
    -2&\lambda_1-2
  \end{bmatrix}\cdot v_1 = 0 \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
    3&-3\\
    -2&2
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    v_{1,1}\\
    v_{1,2}
  \end{bmatrix}=0$

$3v_{1,1} - 3v_{1,2} = 0 \Rightarrow v_{1,1} = v_{1,1}$

$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    1
  \end{bmatrix}$

**Diagonalized Edited after the comment**

$C$ is having eigenvectors as its columns.

$C =\begin{bmatrix}
    1&-3\\
    1&2
  \end{bmatrix}$ To diagonalize $D = C^{-1}AC = C^{-1}(AC)$

$D= \begin{bmatrix}
    4&0\\
    0&-1
  \end{bmatrix}$

**Compute Exp(At)**

$\frac{1}{5}\begin{bmatrix}
   2&3\\
    -1&1
  \end{bmatrix} \bigg(\begin{bmatrix}
    e^{4t}&0\\
    0&e^{-t}
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    1&-3\\
    1&2
  \end{bmatrix}\bigg)=$

Comment: $D$ should be a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Also, your $v_2$ seems incorrect. You should check your calculation again.

Comment: In the title, you ask about computing $\exp(At)$; at the beginning of the question, you’re asking about $\exp(A^T)$ instead; and in your work you do neither, computing $\exp(A)$. Which is it?

Comment: the first $exp(At)$

Comment: Well, that’s not at all what you ended up with. What happened to $t$?